# How can I minimize expression involving logarithms?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to find minimum of this expression:
$$\log _a\left(\frac{4}{9} (3b-1)\right)+8 \log_{\frac{b}{a}}^2(a)-1,$$
where $ 0 < b < a < 1$. I tried

```
Clear[a, b]
    Minimize[Log[a, 4 (3 b - 1)/9] + 8 (Log[b/a, a])^2 - 1, 
     0 < b < a < 1, {a, b}]
```

But I don't get the result. How can I get the result?

Comment: Try with **NMinimize** instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We have a transcendental function of two variables and it is not straightforward to find  global minima under given constraints because `Minimize` behind the scene uses symbolic equation solving functionality and sometimes it has to be supported by user's insight. However using both numerical and symbolic approach we can find an exact global minimum.

We define

```
f[a_,b_]:= Log[a, 4 (3 b - 1)/9] + 8 (Log[b/a, a])^2 - 1
```

To get an insight we play with

```
MinimalBy[ Table[ FindMinimum[{f[a, b], 0 < b < a < 1}, {b}], 
                  {a, 73/100, 95/100, 2/100}], First, 3]
```

> ```
> {{7.00101, {b -> 0.659199}}, {7.02367, {b -> 0.702245}}, {7.04024, {b -> 0.619364}}}
> ```

By  direct inspection we find out where we should look for the global minimum:

```
RegionPlot[{ f[a, b] < 7.01, f[a, b] < 7.001, f[a, b] < 7.0001}, 
            {a, 0.84, 0.9}, {b, 0.64, 0.7}, AxesLabel -> Automatic,
            WorkingPrecision -> 30, PlotPoints -> 60, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]

With quite a good numerical approximation we can find

```
FindMinimum[{f[a, b], 3/5 < b <= 4/5, b < a < 1}, {{a, 0.87}, {b, 2/3}}]
```

> ```
>  {7., {a -> 0.87358, b -> 0.666667}}
> ```

similarily works `NMinimize[{f[a, b], 3/5 < b <= 4/5 < a < 1}, {a, b}]`,
while `Minimize` doesn't work this way, nevertheless restricting one variable we can find an exact result. It is obvious that both partial derivatives have to vanish in the extremum:

```
Solve[Derivative[0, 1][f][a, 2/3] == 0 && 1/2 < a < 1, a]
```

> ```
>  {{a -> (2/3)^(1/3)}}
> ```

```
Minimize[{f[(2/3)^(1/3), b], 1/3 < b < 1}, b] // FullSimplify
```

> ```
> {7, {b -> 2/3}}
> ```

Comment: Your answer and formatting are great. Are there guidelines to doing this efficiently?

Comment: @PaulCommentary Thanks! It's force of my habit, I feel bad when my answer is imperfect, and so usually I have to edit and improve posts. Regarding guidelines I guess they are  all collected in the [help center](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 11):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[a_, b_] := Log[a, 4 (3 b - 1)/9] + 8 (Log[b/a, a])^2 - 1

min = (FindMinimum[{f[a, b], 1/2 < b < a, 0 < a < 1}, {a, b}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 20] // N) /. x_Real :> RootApproximant[x] // 
   ToRadicals

(* {7, {a -> (2/3)^(1/3), b -> 2/3}} *)
```

Verifying that the approximated results are exact

```
{min[[1]] == f[a, b], D[f[a, b], a] == 0, D[f[a, b], b] == 0} /. min[[2]]
  // FullSimplify

(* {True, True, True} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

You do not need numerical guess to find the minimum. Setting both partial derivatives to zero and eliminating variable a is enough.

```
f = Log[a, 4 (3 b - 1)/9] + 8 (Log[b/a, a])^2 - 1 // 
   PowerExpand[#, Assumptions -> {0 < a < 1, 1/3 < b < a}] &;

ee1 = (D[f, a] // Together // Numerator) // 
   PowerExpand[#, Assumptions -> {0 < a < 1, 1/3 < b < a}] &;

ee2 = (D[f, b] // Together // Numerator) // 
   PowerExpand[#, Assumptions -> {0 < a < 1, 1/3 < b < a}] &;

eli = Eliminate[{ee1 == 0, ee2 == 0}, Log[a]]

(*   b Log[b]^5 (6 Log[2] - 6 Log[3] - 3 Log[b] + 3 Log[-1 + 3 b]) == 
     Log[b]^5 (2 Log[2] - 2 Log[3] + Log[-1 + 3 b])   *)

Solve[eli && 1/3 < b < 1, b]

(*   {{b -> 2/3}}   *)

Solve[0 == (ee1 /. b -> 2/3) && 1/3 < a < 1, a]

(*   {{a -> (2/3)^(1/3)}}   *)
```

Comment: The critical point is found . One has else to ground this point is the minimum point.

Comment: This should be no problem for even a undergraduate student.